# Trouble getting WScript.Shell to work from HTA page

Tags: shell, hta, wsh

I have a private HTA application that I want to launch bat files and regular cmd functions (cd, delete, etc.) from.

My script follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var SHELL = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
function buildWorkspace()
{
   SHELL.Run("start cmd /K", 1, true);  
}
</script>
<br/><input type='button' onclick='buildWorkspace();' value='Build Workspace'/>
```

And I keep getting this error: "The system cannot find the file specified."  But I am not passing any file?

I also tried the Exec method like so:

```
var status = SHELL.Exec("cmd");
```

Still not working - get a different error though: "Object doesn't support this property or method"?  I also see a cmd window but with no prompt.

I have tried many different permutations of quotes and commands (tried CD and DIR) still same error.  The final result should allow me to delete a directory and launch a bat file that has three parameters.  Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be pure silliness X 2.

1) The folder separator had to be \ not /.  I was pretty sure you could use either but it only worked when I switched to \.  I was getting messages about invalid options which tipped me off on this one.

2) You have to include the extension on bat files - you can't just go "batfile" you have to use "batfile.bat".

All of this was really odd because if I open a CMD prompt and use the forward slash or omit the .bat extension it works OK.